# "javac -d" is not working on mac osx

Tags: java, macos, javac

I try to compile a total directory java files on my mac book but its not working, same command working on windows

```
javac -d /path/*.java
```

Comment: What is the output your getting?

Comment: Which (dash d) is it?  There is a big difference between the capital D and the lowercase d in javac options.

Comment: There's no reason why it should work. It isn't valid. `-d` specifies a directory, not a .java file (the first of the expansion of `/path/*.java`).

Comment: javac: not a directory: /path/filename.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: @EJP I tried without giving *.java still it not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ javac -help

-d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
```

So you are using the wrong option. If you want to specify the directory that contains the `.java` files to compile, use

```
-sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to set path globally and temporary in mac (lib jar files)

Comment: What do you mean by 'set path globally and temporary'? What are you trying to do?

Comment: We use windows system properties PATH to set path globally(including special jar files) and command prompt to export PATH

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the `-d` option is supposed to take a directory as the argument, and then you still have to provide the files to be compiled?

From the javac documentation

```
-d directory

Set the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist;
javac will not create it. If a class is part of a package, javac puts the class 
file in a subdirectory reflecting the package name, creating directories as 
needed. For example, if you specify -d C:\myclasses and the class is called 
com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is called 
C:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class.

If -d is not specified, javac puts each class files in the same directory as the 
source file from which it was generated.

Note: The directory specified by -d is not automatically added to your user class 
path.
```

My imagination can believe a situation where the windows command expands the asterisk list in such a manner that the first match somehow gets passed as the `-d` parameter, but it wouldn't make it right (or sensible).